# Dax formula argument missing power bi

Tags: powerbi, dax

[image: formula pic]

I have tried, but this formula won't show the error instead of the résult

Answer (score 0):

try this below code-

```
ok = 
SUMMARIZE(
    ATH,
    ATH[ROUTING SEGMENT RES,SE,ME+COR],
    ATH[Call Date],
    ATH[Sales / Non Sales],
    "Your_Column_Name", SUM(ATH[Total])
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the error it's throwing is that you have an empty string for a column name. Try giving is a name with nonzero string length.

I'd expect you'll get a different error in that case because `SUMMARIZE` returns a table rather than a single value.